# How an overrided android life cycle method can run the code after the super call without going to its succeeding life cycle method

Tags: java, android, android-lifecycle, super

Take a look at this.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
}
```

Assume this code is from a normal activity which is a child of `Activity` class. `super.onCreate()` is the first statement in `onCreate()`. This super call must the connecting point to notify the parent class that the `onCreate()` is called in derived class and the next lifecycle method can be called, which is `onStart()` obviously.

#### That is, the order of execution must be like this :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);              <-- ( 1 )
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);          <-- ( 3 )
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();                                 <-- ( 2 )
}
```

#### But it looks like working this way instead :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);              <-- ( 1 )
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);          <-- ( 2 )
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();                                 <-- ( 3 )
}
```

How is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `onStart()` is called *after* `onCreate()`, not *from* it.

Take a look [here](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/d08509363c7fc7c68ca5f61d06ca0ddd441e1495/core/java/android/app/LocalActivityManager.java#L146).

`ActivityThread#startActivityNow()` instantiates the Activity and calls `onCreate()`.

A few lines down you'll see a call to `ActivityThread#handleStartActivity()` which is what calls `onStart()`.

Since there's no async there, Java will wait for `onCreate()` to finish before it continues and eventually calls `onStart()`.

Check the [source comments in Activity.java](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/app/Activity.java) for more details on how Activity lifecycles work.

Comment: And, if it helps, the image in https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle is what I used as a reminder when first getting into Android development. Well, and internalizing the callback structure where "The system invokes each of these callbacks as an activity enters a new state."